# trouble installing and running PYDOE

Tags: python, syntax-error, pydoe

I am having trouble properly installing and using scientific DOE python module described [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/design-your-engineering-experiment-plan-with-a-simple-python-command-35a6ba52fa35):

The page claims to be able to run the DOE module by navigating to your folder location and running it by the command `python main.py`. However when I do this I get an error that reads:

```py
File "main.py", line 21
    print("\nAnalyzing input and building the DOE...",end=' ')
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not know that to do at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python version is too old. That `print()` statement leads to a `SyntaxError` in Python 2.x (even up to Python 2.7), but works in Python 3.x.

Note that Python 2.x is [outdated](https://pythonclock.org/).

One way to fix this problem is to get an updated Python distribution would be to install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), but there are plenty of other options.